# Top Navigation Bar resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

When I resize the browser using the "responsive window" in inspect element, the top navigation also becomes smaller. **I want to maintain the size**. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen !important;
    }
}
body { padding-top: 70px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href= "#" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active "><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Top Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmuhT.png)

[Here is my problem after resizing the image using inspect element's responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6L2E.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that only chrome zooms out, in Firefox it is ok. So just add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

at the head of your page, then it will be seen as the following.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

responsive issue because of meta in head...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,intial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen !important;
    }
}
body { padding-top: 70px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href= "#" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active "><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```